# javascript gallery with JQuery and nyroModal

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I discovered nyroModal extension to JQuery. This seems pretty cool to make a photo gallery with nice effect.
I have the following code... it works when I open it from the file explorer (Finder on Mac), but when I put it on my web server... it does not work anymore. Instead of the cool gallery, the photo on which I click is only displayed in normal web page. Is there something I missed ?
Aisn't this code enough ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/nyroModal.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.nyroModal-1.6.2.pack.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="nyroModal" title="test1" rel="gal" href="./picts/test1.jpg">Gallery Img 1</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lddUnv1R5y0" class="nyroModal" rel="gal" title="Hockey Goal fight">Youtube in gallery</a><br />
<a class="nyroModal" title="test2" rel="gal" href="./picts/test2.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to 700 right on js / css files :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an absolute path. Like `http://www.example.com/css/styles.css` or just `/css/styles.css`.